# When to link "Sdk Assemblies Only"?

Tags: android, linker, xamarin

I'm developing an Android app using Xamarin and Visual Studio 2013. If you go to **Project Properties / Android Options / Linking** there are three options: `None`, `Sdk Assemblies Only`, and `Sdk and User Assemblies`.

My questions is: When would you select the option `Sdk Assemblies Only` option? Don't you always want to include user assemblies in a Release build?

**Update** The word `Linking`is actually used to mean `Unlinking` in the [Xamarin docs](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/). It all makes sense when the text is preprocessed with that condition.

Answer (score 4):

You'd use the `Sdk Assemblies Only` option when you want unused Xamarin.Android assemblies you have linked to your project to be remove when the APK is built. A full list of these assemblies can be [found here.](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/assemblies/)

Say you have added the System.Net assembly to your project but haven't actually used it in your code and forgot to remove it. Specifying the linker option `Sdk Assemblies Only` will cause the build chain to strip the assembly from your final APK thus reducing the overall size of the application.

You can verify this behaviour by looking into the extracting the final APK as a zip file and inspecting the assemblies directory:

[image]

In the above image, you'll see that `System.Net.dll` and `System.Xml.dll` are in the `Don't Link` generated APK whereas they have been removed from the APK which was build with `Sdk Assemblies Only`. These were project references but are never used in the source code, Xamarin detects this through static analysis and then excludes them from the APK.

Comment: As I understand the three options, unused Xamarin.Android assemblies will never get linked into the APK. Or am I wrong?

Comment: The option applies when you have core Xamarin.Android assemblies added to the project but are not used explicitly in the source code. Xamarin doesn't include every core assembly by default when `Don't Link` is enabled.

Comment: So when you select Link: None the APK will actually contain all assemblies? I thought `None` meant `Don't put anything into the APK`.

Comment: `Linking` == `What assemblies to remove from the APK`. And `Sdk Assemblies Only` == `Remove unused Sdk Assemblies`?

Comment: I've read the official docs now and it is obvious that the word `Linking` is used in the sense `Unlinking`. No wonder I got confused.

Comment: `Sdk assemblies` matches your project references against the Xamarin.Android core assemblies and through static analysis, determines which ones will never be used and then removes them from the final APK. It's a process that could do with some further clarification on Xamarins part. I had to disassemble their build process to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

`Xamarin.Android` applications use a **linker** in order to reduce the size of the application.The default value is `SdkOnly`

- `None`: No linking will be attempted.
- `SdkOnly`: Linking will be
  performed on the base class libraries only, not user's assemblies.
- `Full`: Linking will be performed on base class libraries and user
  assemblies.
  [For more details refer here..](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/)
  Note: if you are facing an issue with linking such as

> "GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
>       System.IO.FileNotFoundException: . Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

then recheck your xamarin.Android project settings and set the below tag,

```
<AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>true</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>
```

Hope it will be helpful.